# Cocos2dx positioning CCMenuItem to support full screen toggle

Tags: cocos2d-x

I have added a couple of menu items to my new project and added the ability to toggle fullscreen mode in mac by setting the EAGLView to fullscreen.

However when i toggle to fullscreen and try to click on the menu items the click area is out of place.

What is the best way to deal with this?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry. Forgot i am using CCControlButton not CCMenuItem

Comment: you need to re-position the buttons again if the screen size is changed.